# Nginx rewrite / redirect if query string value does not match

Tags: nginx

This question is little lengthy and I apologize for that. Here is the situation: I have two URLs that point to two different versions of an application.

https://www.codecanisters.in/devapp/ (old version runs on this url)

https://www.codecanisters.in/devapp/neo (new version runs on this url)

Now coming to the query string redirect rules. I have lot of campaigns that run on the basis which source the visitor is coming from. For example say a campaign foo has a source id of 1100, then the visitor would be visiting to the old app with the following url:

https://www.codecanisaters.in/devapp/?source=1100&someothervar=somethingelse so on.

After the release of the new version of the app, I want all visitors to be redirected to the new app i.e. https://www.codecanisters.in/devapp/neo except for if they are coming through few predefined sources for example say

https://www.codecanisaters.in/devapp/?source=1100 or 1200 or 1300 but rest of the visitors no matter what the source is or if no source is provided in the url should all be redirected to the new app.

Ideally if this can be achieved in a location block of nginx config that would be awesome. I know per nginx docs if is evil, but in this situation if we must use if to compare query string I do not mind.

There is another requirement as well when the redirect is done to the new url all the query string should still be retained without causing a redirect loop.

Comment: To be fair, I think this is something your application(s) should handle, and not NGINX.  In pure theory you could do this with `if` commands but that tends to be... problematic.  Especially since when you start taking into account the full location string with arguments.  You need to be more clear about the 'except' cases for where you want them to be permitted and then otherwise get redirected.  It's unclear in the current terms what exactly you're trying to achieve in what circumstances.

Comment: @ThomasWard my except cases are simple, if the url coming in has specific sources say ?source=1100 then they stay on the old application path else everybody gets redirected to the new app i.e. /neo . Hope that makes it clear